# What are the dangers of a hacked Apache Tomcat server?

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7

If a Tomcat7 (on Ubuntu 12.x) gets hacked (caused by weak username/password) what is the hacker able to do? Of course he can deploy .war archives.

But:
Can he get access on the complete file system?
Can he change tomcat/FTP/ubuntu admin passwords?
Or are there no limits at all?

Comment: A threat that people usually don't consider would be processes that are running UNDER tomcat ..  For example, if you had SOLR running, they would be able to delete your entire SOLR Index etc ...  Not good ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about a weak password for the tomcat manager application (that you can use to deploy new webapplications): Well - can you imagine a web application called "remote file explorer"? or "remote shell"? Basically, if you can upload code to servers that gets executed, there's almost no limit.

Well, the limit is set by your admins: Java (and with it Tomcat) can run in a sandbox/security manager. I actually know not many installations that do this. Also, quite a lot of tomcat installations run as the root user - if you lose control over such an instance, you're toast.

So the question you're asking is: "Is it dangerous when attackers can run arbitrary code on my server?" I hate to reveal this, but the answer is "yes".

As of tomcat, I feel that the manager application is nice for debugging, but not something you want to deploy on a production system, visible to the world. But that's only a very small part of the hardening process.

Oh, and even though it might not exactly fit in this context, but you might want to look at [Java/Tomcat hacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422573), I just found this scrolling by - a nice alternative vulnerability to a weak password.

Comment: what are the exploits beyond the stupidly bundled manager application, which i am sure lots of people mistakenly never remove. Are there other concerns to be bothered with? The catalina.policy is not enforced by default, correct? Should one setup more measures if only MY war is deployed?