# aws network traffic high due to folder 29881 and fake.cfg

Tags: amazon-web-services, struts2, tomcat7

I am running a java website on an amazon aws instance (Its a linux server). I have installed apache on port 80 and tomcat on port 8080. When i access the website, it default going to port 80(`apache`) and then it redirects to port 8080(`tomcat`). All i have done is correctly and the site is working well. But my issue is after i make live the site in an instance(amazon aws instance), there is one folder with name 29881 and a file fake.cfg is generated automatically under tmp folder. After these files are generated the network traffic on my instance is becoming ver high (almost 1000mb) and i need to pay to amazon for this amount of data transfer.

I know this is a type of hacking but anyone familiar with how can i avoid this hacking. The high traffic is generated on the server only after the folder `29881` and file `fake.cfg` generated inside the folder. Please help me to fix this.

As i said i have built th website in struts2 framework and hibernate. But when a check on the web that say struts2 xwork causes issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422573/java-tomcat-hacked). Anyone please refer this and let me know whether this cuases any issue. If yes please suggest how can i fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like you either you are using a version of tomcat with some kind of easily-exploitable vulnerability, or you otherwise have failed to secure your system properly.

[Liz Quilty says](http://blog.rimuhosting.com/2013/08/09/old-tomcat-5-5-installs-being-exploited/):

> We have noticed a couple of people running older tomcat 5.5 installs, and these are being exploited . The main thing we noticed were slowdowns on bandwidth as well as CPU along with a few odd other things running as tomcat user

In that post, she specifically mentions `fake.cfg` as one of the files dropped by the bot that exhibits the high-bandwidth outbound behavior you described.

http://blog.rimuhosting.com/2013/08/09/old-tomcat-5-5-installs-being-exploited/

Older releases of later versions of tomcat also have numerous vulnerabilities.

Comment: Yah but i have already using tomcat7 version on my website and i have checked the checked all the security option with amazon team and they says its perfect.

Comment: Okay, but is it the latest version of 7?  As I mentioned, older releases of *all versions* have vulnerabilities.  Also, what an Amazon representative may have said about the "security option" (whatever that might mean) is not, in any sense, relevant.  Your web server is accessible from the Internet, and the vulnerability is in the the exposed web server, either due to a vulnerability in the software or in your code, or perhaps a weak password.  There is no AWS configuration that can secure a system that can be compromised via ports that are deliberately exposed.

Comment: I have found one mistake in my code. Actually i have used struts 2.2 jar file in my project but in my struts.xml file i have added the doctype as <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">. Mean i have point to struts 2.0 dtd even i am using struts2.2 jars. Is that cause any problem in my code?

Answer (score 2):

I recently bumped into the same problem..
I found fake.cfg and 29881 execution file under my /tmp folder
The hacker's ip is from 222.186.24.174 which using his port 29881 as a passive connection to my server.. (maybe that is why the execution file is called 29881)
The hacker is using the loophole in Struts 2..
http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/security-bulletins.html

For me, he is using the loophole s2-016 (some other loopholes I found they used are s2-013, s2-009 and s2-005)
This issue can be resolved by updating your Struts 2 to the latest as 2.3.16
(Yea~ it is very painful to manage those lib dependences again)

You can use "ps -ef" to see if there is any suspicious pid running under user "tomcat", which hacker is used as their remote role to execute what they have uploaded through Struts2 loophole
And "sudo lsof -p (the pid)" to see what is opened and executed by the hacker..

Hope this information is helpful to the people suffer from the same problem.. :)

Most useful page I found is this one:
http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/chinese-underground-creates-tool-exploiting-apache-struts-vulnerability/
Which basically described how they did it..

Comment: Yah now i am trying to update the struts version to 2.3 but i know that is not that much easy. Anyway i will try this and will come back.

Comment: The upgrade to struts 2.3 was a fail. But when i try update only xwork file the project gets worked. So in my current project only struts xwok jar is updated and now i can find the project is running. But before moving this to live serverm may i know whether upgrading only xwork jar on the project is a good method?